# How to check if line only contains digits?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I check whether first line of a file contains only digits?

```
>> with open("text.txt") as f:
        line = f.readline()

>> line
 '0.23\t5.44\t-4.33\t2.45\t-1.23\n'
>> line.isdigit()
False
```

Comment: You mean only digits and spaces, right?

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo, the line includes spaces, but is there a way to ignore them?

Comment: I think you could do something like `all(chunk.isnumeric() for chunk in line.strip().split())`

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo, thanks but I'm getting a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'`

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: Looks like he's using Python2. This works in Python3

Comment: @Daniel Mesejo, Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want true for your input it looks like you want to split your line on whitespace and then test to see if they are all (decimal) numbers.

"a b".split() returns [a,b] and float(str) will throw an exception if the string isn't a valid float.

```
def isNumbers(string):
  try:
    for n in string.split():
      print n
      f = float(n)
    return True
  except:
    return False

print( isNumbers(line) )
```